# Equivalent circuit of CM and DM EMI filter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

This is the diagram of an EMI filter consisting of both CM and DM filters:
[image: EMI filter structure: common mode and differential mode]

This is the equivalent circuit of the CM filter:
[image: CM Filter eq ckt]

Could someone explain why in the equivalent circuit, it's Lcm and not 2Lcm?

Also in the DM filter equivalent circuit shown below:
[image: DM filter eq ckt]

Why does Lcm,leakage occur?

Source: J. L. Kotny, T. Duquesne and N. Idir, "Design of EMI filters for DC-DC converter," 2010 IEEE Vehicle Power and Propulsion Conference, Lille, France, 2010, pp. 1-6, doi: 10.1109/VPPC.2010.5729047.

Comment: ORion - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that original content must be correctly referenced. For online sources, the original webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (the references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Please can you [edit] your question to include the required source links for the original images? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you for informing me. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Could someone explain why in the equivalent circuit, it's Lcm and not
> 2Lcm?*

With Line_1 and Line_2 shorted together, there are two inductors effectively in parallel (Lcm || Lcm) but, they share a common core and, act as one inductor of value Lcm. Here's how the shorting affects the analysis: -
[image]

Regarding the CM choke, consider this: if you wound an inductor from one wire it might have 100 μH but, if you wound it with two thinner wires and joined the ends, it would still be 100 μH.

> *Why does Lcm,leakage occur?*

Well, as hard as we try to make the two windings identical and perfectly share any flux in the core, inevitably, there will be a little leakage flux and, this produces leakage inductance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Well, I understood the shorting of the nodes, however, I'm still finding it hard to understand why Lcm would be considered as one inductor. Could you give some mathematical proof for this?

Comment: @ORion It doesn't really matter for the diff. mode circuit if you place a smaller leakage inductor in each branch or one larger leakage inductor in one branch. The diff. mode current has to flow through both branches anyway. That is the same reason why the two LDM's are absorbed in a single equivalent inductor. If you feel better, you can *name* this combined leakage inductor also *'2 LCM,leakage'*. But, the value of the component would be the same regardless.

Comment: @ORion two inductors of the same value and on the same core when excited together, behave as one inductor of the same value; it's a fundamental principle of magnetics. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.