# Equivalent Circuit of CM EMI filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, emc, emi-filtering

Actually, someone already asked this question before.
But I have another question here.

This is the diagram of an EMI filter in both CM and DM filters:

[image]

This is the equivalent circuit of the CM filter:
[image]

I don't know why it's Ldm/2 in this equivalent circuit.

(By the way I know why LISN has 25 Ω and also understand the route of the CM current's flow)

Could someone explain it please?

Comment: Could you [edit] and add the link to the previous question, for context? *If necessary*, maybe also add what the difference is between the questions.

Comment: Probably, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669439/equivalent-circuit-of-cm-and-dm-emi-filter?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Lcm's are coupled (presumably k ~ 1) so have a parallel equivalent of Lcm.

Ldm's are not coupled so have a parallel equivalent of Ldm/2.